# T-SQL - Joining to database with derived name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to be able to join to a different database (on the same server), and the name of the database I need to join to is dependent on the record being examined.  I've got something along the lines of

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN orderdetail od ON od.okey = o.okey
INNER JOIN scheduledetail scheddet on scheddet.odkey = od.odkey
INNER JOIN schedules sched on sched.schedid = scheddet.schedid
INNER JOIN databases db on db.dbdate = sched.releasedate
INNER JOIN [db.dbname].detail det on det.odkey = od.odkey
```

However, as far as I can tell transact SQL won't allow this kind of join syntax.  Any ideas?

Comment: INNER JOIN dbname.schema.field det on det.odkey = od.odkey

Comment: You're gonna have to user [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: So, for this field with the dbname, is the "Detail" table the same in all of these dbs? How many dbs are we talking about here?

Comment: I wish.  Basically, there's a separate database for each day (going back maybe four years?) and the detail table in each one contains various detailed information related to that day's activity.

Comment: Ug. Well, to be honest, the query above simply can't work. The select * gives you every column, but by your definition, these would change on a row by row basis. (Since each row could connect to a separate table, each with its own column count and data types). If you are sending back the same column/datatype there is a trick, but otherwise you'll need 4*365 different queries for this.

Answer (score 0):

If all the detail tables have the same columns, you could create a view that wraps all of them.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max);

SELECT
  @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ' UNION ALL ','CREATE VIEW unified_details AS ')
+ 'SELECT *,'+QUOTENAME([dbname])+' AS [dbname] FROM '+QUOTENAME([dbname])+'.[dbo].[detail]'
FROM databases;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN orderdetail od ON od.okey = o.okey
INNER JOIN scheduledetail scheddet on scheddet.odkey = od.odkey
INNER JOIN schedules sched on sched.schedid = scheddet.schedid
INNER JOIN databases db on db.dbdate = sched.releasedate
INNER JOIN unified_details det on det.odkey = od.odkey and db.dbname = det.dbname
```

Comment: Somewhat unorthodox but this approach let me do what I need to do in the short term.  Unfortunately the size of the data involved meant I had to restrict the scope of the view so I'll still need to come up with a dynamic solution going forward.